# Laravel - How to use captcha for api

Tags: laravel, api

i've api api using laravel 9. and front end using codeigniter. i want create captcha in front end but can verified at api. thank for answering.

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        // 'captcha' => 'required|captcha'
    ]);
```

using this mews/captcha not working when validate in api because it's need crsf token.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package:

```
composer require hpd/captcha
```